# How do I join two models in Django by id?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have two models as shown below with just a few fields:

```
class Query(models.Model):
    query_text = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    variable = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)

class Statistic(models.Model):
    query = models.ForeignKey(Query, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    processing_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    module = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
```

My target is to perform a JOIN using the id of the two models. The SQL query equivalent to it would be :

```
SELECT * FROM statistic S JOIN query Q ON S.query_id = Q.id
```

I understand select_related or prefetch_related could do the trick? I don't know which one to use to perform the join. 
I'd appreciate some help on that. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `select_related` for this. You can make sure that JOIN is using by calling queryset's `query` attribute, which show you raw SQL statement:

```
print(Statistic.obects.select_related("query").query)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've to use `select_related` here as you've a ForeignKey relationship. (`prefetch_related` is for ManyToMany fields).

So,

```
some_id_value = 12
stats_queryset = Statistic.obects.select_related("query").filter(id=some_id_value)
```

Comment: P.S. 'queryset' is the nomenclature used extensively in Django and has nothing to do with the 'query' variable that you've used.